# Customising left/right page headers

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm completely new to using headers and am struggling to understand the options of the packages I'm using.

I took this header setup from a friend:

```
\documentclass[11pt,onecolumn]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,textcase}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\nouppercase\rightmark}
\geometry{a4paper,inner=40mm,outer=15mm,top=15mm,bottom=15mm,footskip=5mm,headsep=3mm,headheight=15mm,twoside}

\begin{document}
\title{Some title}
\maketitle

\chapter{The first chapter}
some text!
\section{The first section}
Some more text!

\end{document}
```

This file is a {book}, and what I'd like is for the left-page header to give only the current chapter, and the right-page header to give only the current section.

However, the header is currently the same on both pages and shows both the chapter *and* the section.

I'm sure this is a simple fix, but I'm having trouble knowing where to look for info.

thanks!

Comment: Did you used `twoside` in documentclass option? i.e. `\documentclass[twoside]{book}`.

Comment: @jagathAR I'm using twoside in the geometry package, but that's all as far as I can tell. I'll update the code in the question with more info on whats in the latex header.

Comment: A minimal working example would be helpful.

Comment: @johannes_B good point... I've now added something which compiles. You'll have to add some dummy text to add extra pages to see the header, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe  you are looking for

```
\documentclass[11pt,onecolumn]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\geometry{a4paper,inner=40mm,outer=15mm,top=15mm,bottom=15mm,footskip=5mm,headsep=3mm,headheight=15mm,twoside}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\nouppercase\leftmark}% LE -> Left part on Even pages
\fancyhead[RO]{\nouppercase\rightmark}% RO -> Right part on Odd pages

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\title{Some title}
\author{Author}
\maketitle
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Note that I have used `\geometry` before `\pagestyle{fancy}`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I had never considered that the ordering of things like \geometry{} in the preamble could be important! I'll have to watch out for that in future.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please check whether the following works for you:

```
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\nouppercase\rightmark}
```

The MWE will now looks like:

```
\documentclass[11pt,onecolumn]{book}
\usepackage{geometry,lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,textcase}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\nouppercase\rightmark}
\geometry{a4paper,inner=40mm,outer=15mm,top=15mm,bottom=15mm,footskip=5mm,headsep=3mm,headheight=15mm,twoside}

\begin{document}
\title{Some title}
\maketitle

\chapter{The first chapter}
some text!
\section{The first section}
Some more text!

\lipsum\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Tried it and it doesn't seem to change anything unfortunately. Don't know if it matters but i did clean out all the auxiliary files after the change.

Comment: Please add some text after `\section{}` and check next two pages. Add `\usepackage{lipsum}` in preamble and add `\lipsum\lipsum` after `\section{}` and check the pages.

Comment: @JagathAR: While this might be solution anyone seeing it has to build up a compilable document of this fragment -- this is not our preferred way of answering questions ;-)

Comment: I tried the change in my full document, which does have text. I put some dummy text in the working example from the question and it still didn't change as far as I can tell. [Here is a screenshot of what it looks like](http://imgur.com/xQXTxY6) - still shows both the chapter and section on each page.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer. Sorry. I have now put the MWE.

Comment: @JagathAR: The TeX.SX force is strong in you ;-) (+1)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer. Yea. :-)